# expresión regular que no permita caracteres especiales en una cadena

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

una consulta por casualidad tienen alguna expresión regular

que no permita caracteres especiales, sin un tamaño límite de la cadena tenía esta

```
[A-Za-z0-9][:]{1}
```

tengo esta que básicamente solo permite una cadena de 20 caracteres que solo sean letras y números, y con esta podría verificar la negación con un if para validar si existen caracteres especiales, pero también pasa que tengo que validar que exista al menos uno de estos [:] donde sea , entonces nose si talvez sepan de una variante.

Comment: Esa expresión sólo permite una letra o número seguida de dos puntos. No sé como puede ser posible que extraiga 20 caracteres

Comment: Probablemente, consigas mejores respuestas si les preguntas a los que saben sobre regex en general y no limitarte a java